# Simple Login with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to make a simple login with JPA but i really don't get how i should go about doing it coming from a direct JDBC background.This is what i have :

```
public boolean login(String CID,String password) {  

        try{
            EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
            entr.begin();

        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.clientID = ?1 AND c.password = ?2");
        query.setParameter(1, CID).setParameter(2, password); 
        try{ 
        Clients c = (Clients) query.getSingleResult();
        return true;
        }catch(javax.persistence.NoResultException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
        finally{
        em.close();
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work. Glassfish doesn't specifically give me a reason with it's bunch of errors. Is my logic right ? or there is a better way to do this ? Thanks

Comment: What errors? Show logs

Comment: @MGorgon i get this `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.models.Clients cannot be cast to org.models.Clients` "Clients" is the entity database.

Comment: @MGorgon regardless of the error, is the logic correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, logic is correct. Try with TypedQuerry, so you don't have to cast:

```
    TypedQuery<Clients> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.clientID = :id AND c.password = :pass", Clients.class);
    query.setParameter("id", CID);
    query.setParameter("pass", password); 
    try{ 
    Clients c = query.getSingleResult();
```

second thing, I think that you don't have to close entityManager. If you injected it, the container will carry about it.
Also, it would be better to perform SELECT COUNT so the Client will not be downloaded from database. It will look like this:

```
    TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Clients c WHERE c.clientID = :id AND c.password = :pass", Long.class);
    query.setParameter("id", CID);
    query.setParameter("pass", password); 
    return query.getSingleResult() > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i tried the second approach per your advice but i have an error at the return statement. `bad operand types for binary operator '>' First type : clients, Second type : int`

Comment: @beginningperl yes, because you must change the type of TypedQuery to Long class

Comment: Thanks the first solution worked. the second started giving errors like `java.lang.ClassCastException: Clients cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`  But i wish it worked though since you said it's better.

Comment: When you change your typedQuery to this: TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Clients c WHERE c.clientID = :id AND c.password = :pass", Long.class); it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

Or rather. You should add a Logger to your code. Then you should wrote like this

```
try {
    Clients c = (Clients) query.getSingleResult();
    return true;
} catch {NoResultException e){
    log.debug("Problem to login for user % ", CID , e);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your right MGorgon. Did a copy paste of Nassims Answers. 
Should have profread my answer a little bit better :-). 
But I have change it so that it catch the same Exception that BeginningPerl have in his comment.

Comment: Thanks Viggo but MGorgon's solution saved the day

Comment: Since it is an login Module. I would suggest that your Catch should catch all Exception. So that error in your system, doesn't leak out to the user that try to login. 
But in most case, I do agree with MGorgon. You should only catch Exception that is thrown, as you have done in your code.